# Cocos2D Particles Following b2Body?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone, particle-system

I am able to implement particle system in cocos2d and now i want to attach my particle with a dynamic b2Body, so that, it can follow the body.

I have found a tutorial about Cocos2D Particles Following b2Body at [this site]. But not understand "how to use" section. Can any one please tell me, how can i attach my particle with my b2Body?

Comment: The site you mentioned solves the problem of world moving and is a bit overkill for what you try to achieve. Can you please post what you have so far? It should just work to set the emitter to a CCSprite and schedule a function to change the position and rotation of that CCSprite according to the b2body

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should create an object that contain the b2body.

Secondly, you should connect the object to the b2body. 
If you don't know how to do this, you can read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491450/moving-box2d-bodies-like-ccsprite-objects/10495687#10495687)

Lastly, you should just add the particle system as the child of the object.